# Firebase DB structure for scale

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I understand that this question could be open-ended, but I would like the answer. I have a firebase db and a model called widgets. Each user can obtain many widgets, and each company can create multiple widgets. Right now I save widgets to a "widget" child - key and again to the specific company, under the company key and "widget" child - key. Once the user accepts the widget, I save it there also.

Is this a normal process? I have another model that I save in 6 different locations. Ahhhhh.... I dont know if I should keep going if my whole db structure is not correct. I want to know this answer based on a large scale of users. Or should I just be saving the unique key under the userID and then "get" the keys, then the info? That just sounds like more work and I would rather have the speed on the user side and let the db take time. I guess I also just dont know if the db can handle that much updating. 3 updates per widget * 100,000 users... Will this cause issues?

Comment: In general: data duplication is quite normal in NoSQL databases. The amount of duplication usually depends on amount of variation in the use-cases your app supports, because in NoSQL you model the data for the way your app uses it. I recommend reading [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/) and viewing [Firebase for SQL developers](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s).

Comment: When asking questions like this: don't describe your data model, but show it. One advantage of Firebase is that you can easily export your JSON from the database and add it to your question. Showing code for specific use-cases that you're concerned about would also help to make this more concrete.

Comment: I would, but its alot of data/json.... lol

Comment: We don't need all of your data - just a snippet of it to illustrate the data structure. A couple of nodes worth is usually enough. Having that structure (as text please, no images) helps us to help you!